# Angular 4 GroupBy Array Data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, group-by

I have an array which looks like:

```
var data = [
  {
    student: "sam",
    English: 80,
    Std: 8
  },
  {
    student: "sam",
    Maths: 80,
    Std: 8
  },
  {
    student: "john",
    English: 80,
    Std: 8
  },
  {
    student: "john",
    Maths: 80,
    Std: 8
  }
];
```

and I need to get the total marks irrespective of subject for student sam.

By filtering data array by student name and then looping the filtered data, can get the individual student total marks.

Is there any **groupBy** function as similar to SQL in Typescript.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/7124761 what you looking for?

Comment: do you want something like this  {student:"sam", English: 80,  Maths: 80, Std: 8},{student:"john", English: 80, Maths, Std: 8},

Comment: like for student "sam" the value = 160(total of marks)

Comment: what is std? there is only 3 fields student,subject and std?

Comment: std- in what standard the student i studying. Yes there is only 3 fields

Comment: Ok. I can give an answer but need some time.

Comment: this is working but don't know if is what you want..
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5xfyz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it can be done with a simple reduce method on the array. Reduce will iterate over an array and pass each item into the provided predicate function. Each iteration should return the accumulator obj/array/val.

I wasn't sure what you wanted the data structure to be, but you can control the structure by the inner working of the function you pass to `reduce`.

```
  studentScores = this.data.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    const key = Object.keys(item)
      .filter(k => k !== 'student')
      .filter(k => k !== 'Std')[0];
    const prevValue = accumulator[item.student] || 0;
    const studentName = item.student;
    accumulator[studentName] = prevValue + item[key];
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
```

I posted a working example in a stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcjzzf

Answer (score -2):

You have to do it using dictionary. Easy way to grouping is used a map.there mark's name is changing so the task is difficult.This is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h75cqk) link.

Comment: linked solution can become outdated. You should post reason and example in your answer too.

Comment: thanks for the down vote. you can see my answer. that's why I post stackBlitz